# Simulator is not launching from xcode but app is building

Tags: react-native-ios

**Problem**

I run react native ios app from xcode, it build app but the simulator is not launching.

**Tried**

1. When I try from terminal, simulator is  launching and app is running.
2. I clean xcode derivedData and simulator cache too but its did not success.
3. I even restarted my laptop too.
4. I create swift project from xcode, it build and launch simulator every time.

**Planning**

1. Uninstall and re-install xcode.

Any suggestion would be grateful.